# "Da" position in subordinate clauses

Tags: word-order, subordinate-clause, adverbial

Why does *da* change the position in this subordinate clause?

> Meine Tante wohnt in Berlin, weil … Sie hat *da* eine große Wohnung.
>
> Meine Tante wohnt in Berlin, weil sie eine groβe Wohnung *da* hat.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It doesn't need to change position. The person who provided the solution changed the position for whatever reason.

Both positions of "da" are possible in the main clause, too:

> Sie hat da eine große Wohnung.
> Sie hat eine große Wohnung da.

If the task of the exercise is just to convert the given main clause into a "weil ..." clause, then the correct solution is:

> Meine Tante wohnt in Berlin, weil ______. Sie hat da eine große Wohnung.
> ==> Meine Tante wohnt in Berlin, weil sie **da** eine groβe Wohnung hat.

In other words, the change of position of "da" is entirely optional and has nothing to do with whether it's a main clause or a subordinate clause.

Comment: I'd add another version: "Da hat sie eine große Wohnung."

Comment: Are you sure? "Meine Tante wohnt in Berlin, weil sie eine grosse Wohnung hat **da**." sounds *extremely* strange to me, and entirely ungrammatical. I do not believe that the possible position of "da" has nothing to do with whether it's in a main or subordinate clause - it is indeed more restricted in a subordinate one.

Comment: You’re right, **da** cannot come after the verb in the subordinate clause (nothing can, really). The subordinate clause corresponding to “Sie hat eine große Wohnung da.” is “…, weil sie eine große Wohnung da hat.”

Comment: @HalvarF Thanks for your help and explanations

Comment: @StephanKolassa Am I sure of what? The correct version with a "late" *da* is already in the question: "weil sie eine groβe Wohnung da hat." I don't know where you found the  version "weil sie eine grosse Wohnung hat da". I agree - that would sound wrong.

Comment: You write "the change of position of "da" is entirely optional and has nothing to do with whether it's a main clause or a subordinate clause." That is what I wonder about. I believe that the position is more free in a main clause and less free in a subordinate clause (and it seems like you agree), so it indeed is influenced by what clause we have...

Comment: Instead of "Meine Tante wohnt in Berlin, weil … Sie hat da eine große Wohnung." I would prefer "Meine Tante wohnt in Berlin, *denn* sie hat da eine große Wohnung."

Answer (score 3):

You might also consider another solution.
*Da* may be used causally (in the sense of *weil*, i.e. 'because'). Another possibility is for indicating locality in the sense of *dort*, i.e. 'over there'). That would make it

Meine Tante wohnt in Berlin, da sie dort eine große Wohnung hat.

In this case, *da* is used in the same sense as *weil* (causal) and being replaced by *dort* indicating locality.

Comment: Thanks for your reply

Comment: Would "...da sie da eine grosse Wohnung hat" work?